# Deferencing Null Pointer Error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am kinda confuse with this piece of code. It keeps give me the error of "Deferencing Null Pointer".

bookStore.java

```
 @Override
protected store createOutlet (String storeName, String storeType) {
    store theStore = null;
        theStore.setStoreName(storeName); //getting Deferencing Null Pointer Error
        theStore.setStoreType(storeType);
    return theStore;
}
```

storeProducer.java

```
public abstract class storeProducer {
protected abstract store createOutlet(String storeName, String storeType);

public store createNewStore(String storeName, String storeType) {
    store newStore = createOutlet(storeName, storeType);
    newStore.createStore();

    return newStore;
}
```

store.java

```
public abstract class store extends Observable {
abstract void createStore();
```

What the problem in it? I already tried like throwing the exception but still not working.

Comment: What do you think `store theStore = null;` does?

Comment: I am ware of it, but if i remove it, my variables "theStore" will be shown not initialized. but if i create an instance it shows error of store is abstract, cannot be instantianed.

Comment: You **must** have a concrete `store` type to use one at runtime. Use that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

`theStore` is `null` and `theStore.anything()` will try to dereference the null pointer.

It seems you wanted to create a `store` instance, you can do that with `new`:

```
store theStore = new AnyNonAbstractClassDerivingFromStore();
```

Comment: it doesn't allow me as it created as an abstract in the store.java

Comment: Oh true, you need to `new` a non-abstract sub-class of `store`.